# how do I get diff to stop mangling function docblocks?

Tags: diff

If I add a function to my code, my diff looks like this:

```
 }

 /**
+ * My new function docblock.
+ */
+function my_function($foo) { }
+
+/**
  * The next function's docblock.
  *
```

Is there a way to stop diff from mangling this?

I tried git's --patience flag but that produces the same result.

Answer (score 0):

If what you expect would a better diff which would "understand" the presence in the comparison of a comment block and have the diff aligned in a way which does not split those blocks, you are off currently.

The internal algorithm of "diff" automatically aligns the block to the line with the greatest number for which the difference is still 'true'. For example rather than

```
 }

+/**
+ * My new function docblock.
+ */
+function my_function($foo) { }
+
 /**
  * The next function's docblock.
  *
```

Diff will always return the result that you described in your question. Many tools which are based on GNU diff suffer from this problem.

Answer (score 0):

What you want is a tool that compares program structures, not "lines of text".

See our [SmartDifferencer](http://www.semanticdesigns.com/Products/SmartDifferencer) tools that compare the source text of programs, using the structure of the programming language as its guide.  There's a SmartDifferencer for many languages (C++, C#, Java, COBOL, ...)

For OP's example, it should simply note that the function (and its docblock) have been added.